# Log4j don't catch javax.el exception

Tags: log4j

I'm getting a `Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` but this don't show in my file log4j, just in server.log (Jboss EAP 7). I already configured the log4j but didn't work:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=\${user.home}/myproject/log/app.log
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%c:%L] - %m%n

log4j.logger.javax.faces=ERROR
log4j.logger.javax.el=INFO
log4j.logger.com.sun.faces=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this exception does not appear in your log4j-generated log is more likely a code problem than a configuration problem.

If you don't catch the exception somehow and pass it to a logger then it won't show up in the log4j-generated log and will instead be written to System.out (which in a server environment usually means server log).

Since this is a subclass of `RuntimeException` it's not a checked exception (see [the javadoc of RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true) and [PropertyNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException.html)) which is why I'm guessing you don't have it surrounded by a try-catch block.

You need to do something like:

```
try{

    //Code that might throw the PropertyNotFoundException goes here

}catch(PropertyNotFoundException e){

    logger.error("Some kind of error message here!", e);

    //Do something to handle the exception...

}
```